Line chart with VBA, displaying the last 5 values of 3 columns (3 lines)
I got tasked to create a diagram that visualizes the results of the last 5 subjects that get tested. Each subject gets tested in 5 different points, and all of them  have the same limit value that should also be represented in a graph.
Let me use a dummy table to explain:



SUBJECTS
point1
point2
point3
LIMIT1
LIMIT2




A
0,2
0,1
0,1
1
-1


B
0,3
-0,2
0,2
1
-1


C
0,4
0,2
0,3
1
-1


D
0,3
0,7
0,4
1
-1


E
0,1
0,1
0,5
1
-1


F
0,4
-0,4
0,6
1
-1



This table is ever growing, where new subjects are added everyday (this is already coded in vba). The number of points are always the same and the number of limits too. From this table what I have to do is plot a line chart with three lines to each "point". Only taking the last 5 rows (in this case from row B to row F).
In each of the  subjects diagrams both limits should always be represented along side the values to one of the points. In the following an example chart for point 1:

I know how to this without vba, by using the offset function. But for some reason most functions are not working with me. So I really need to do it using vba. Problem is I have no clue how to select the last 5 of a dynamic table. Any help?

It would be useful to see the relevant parts of the existing code

nothing is really relevant. The code simply allows for a new subject, aka row to be added

To change the X- and Y-values of a series, you can write to it's properties XValues and Values. The following routine will set the data of all series to the last n values of a range of data. It assumes that all columns are represented by a series and the first column (in your case SUBJECTS) holds the x-values.
Sub setChartToLastLines(ch As Chart, r As Range, Optional rowCount As Long = 5)
    Dim colData As Range
    With r.CurrentRegion
        Set colData = .Columns(1)
        Debug.Print colData.Address
        If .Rows.Count > rowCount Then
            Set colData = colData.Offset(.Rows.Count - rowCount).Resize(rowCount)
        End If
    End With
    
    With ch
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .FullSeriesCollection.Count
            .FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = colData.Offset(0, i)
            .FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = colData
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

You pass as parameters the chart itself that should be modified, and a cell or range within your data. The routine will calculate a range holding the last n values (colData) for the X-Axis. The values for Y-axis are retrieved with the Offset-function.
You can call it for example like this (my data and chart are on the same sheet):
Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Debug.Print .ChartObjects.Count
        setChartToLastLines .ChartObjects(1).Chart, .Range("A1"), 5
    End With
End Sub

Add this call at the end of the routine that writes your data and the chart should point to the last 5 entries.

Assuming that there is the chart on the sheet already with ChartDataRange Sheet_name!A2:D6
This code will change it always for the last five rows of the data table.
Sub newlines()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("sheet5")   'name of the worksheet

lastrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

sh.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData sh.Range(Cells(lastrow - 4, "A"), Cells(lastrow, "D"))


End Sub


